# How can I restore the shape of syphon tubing?

Tags: tubing

I recently purchased a new auto syphon that came with a length of tubing.  The way it had been packaged resulted in the tubing being folded and this is causing problems as it has a tendency to kink at these points and disrupt my syphon.

Is there a way to restore or condition the tubing so it kinks less?

Comment: I don't know where you purchased the tubing from but if it was from Northern Brewer contact customer service at info@northernbrewer.com and we will send you a replacement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try putting it in warm water for a few minutes, then pulling it straight and letting it cool.

Comment: By warm water, I actually meant hot.  Hot enough to make the plastic pliable.

Comment: This did the trick nicely.  I used water at 75c and ran it through a couple a couple of times, pulled it straight and then allowed it to cool while hanging straight.

Comment: Note that vinyl tubing should not go over 80C.

Answer (score 3):

I'd certainly give Baka's suggestion a try for the long term maintenance, but honestly this stuff is too cheap to mess around with long.  You can by this kind of tubing at nearly any hardware or home improvement store and it really is cheap.

My experience is that once it's badly kinked, it never really is right again.  The easiest thing to do is replace it and use Baka's advice to keep it from kinking.

Answer (score 2):

Mine usually stay semi-coiled until I run strike or sparge water through them and hang them up.  After that, they'll stay straight.

Answer (score 2):

I often have a kink in my tubing where I hang it over a hook to drip for storage.  But when I run some warm PBW (cleaning) solution through it on the next brew day that kink relaxes out.

So a soak in very warm water, in side and out should loosen it back up.  Then you can coil it nice as it cools and you should be fine.  OR just clip one end of it up so it all lays loosely in a slack line.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a hair drier while hanging it. This works well on Tygon tubing that is temperature resistant.